# Is it true that $\operatorname{rank}(M) = m$ if and only if $\operatorname{det}(MM^T) >0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider an $m$ by $n$ matrix $M$ with $m<n$ whose elements are real.

> Is it true that $\operatorname{rank}(M) = m$ if and only if
>   $\operatorname{det}(MM^T) >0$?

Comment: Hint: rank(AB)$\leq$min{rank(A),rank(B)}

Comment: definitely give the hint by @GFR a try, it's very convenient - just keep also in mind that the rank of a linear map is the dimension of the corresponding image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to see this is that $MM^\top$ is the [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix), whose determinant is the square of the $m$-dimensional volume of the parallelepiped spanned by the rows of $M$.

Another way is to see that by doing row operations, when $\text{rank}\, M = m$, we obtain
$$EM = \begin{bmatrix} I_{m\times m} & O_{m\times n} \end{bmatrix},$$
where $E$ is a product of $m\times m$ elementary matrices. Then $$E(MM^\top)E^\top = I_{m\times m}\tag{$\star$},$$ so $MM^\top$ is nonsingular.  Indeed, from ($\star$) we conclude that $MM^\top=E^{-1}(E^\top)^{-1}= (E^\top E)^{-1}$, so $\det(MM^\top) = 1/(\det E)^2 > 0$. It is easy to see the same way that when $\text{rank}\, M<m$, we end up with a singular matrix.

Comment: @ajotatxe: See my edit. Thanks.